# Mostrar Activity dentro de otra Activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps

> ¿Cómo se puede implementar un Activity dentro de otro Activity?

Mi idea es mostrar una Activity principal en la cual tengo varios textos e información, y dentro de esta Activity principal quiero agregar un cuadro donde se muestre un segundo Activity, en el que se muestra un mapa de Google Maps y se puede trabajar con ese mapa en segundo plano...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo los códigos de ambas Activity, lo que necesito es un ejemplo de cómo se podría implementar un cuadro de una segunda Activity dentro de otro Activity (o Fragment en caso de no poderse en alguna Activity)

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo realices el ejemplo del tutorial que agrego @Matias , cuando entiendas como realizarlo usaras un MapFragment para cargar tu Mapa en la aplicación. Por cierto no agregues la misma pregunta mejor realiza una buena basada en [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 1):

**Lo que deseas realizar es precisamente el objetivo de los [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)**

> [**Un Fragment representa un comportamiento o una parte de la interfaz
>   de usuario en una Activity.**](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

Básicamente para convertir una `Activity` en `Fragment` necesitas:

- Tu clase debe extender de la clase `Fragment`  en lugar de `Activity` o `AppCompatActivity`, etc...
- Usar `onCreateView()` instead of `onCreate()`.
- En lugar de usar findViewById() para buscar las referencias de las vistas debes usar `getView().findViewById()`

Como ejemplo te muestro una `Activity`:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivityLeoaica extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("Elenasys was here!");
    }

}
```

y ahora la misma `Activity` convertida a `Fragment`:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FragmentLeoaica extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("Elenasys was here!");

        return view;
    }


}
```

Un `Fragment` se puede considerar un pedazo de UI , por ejemplo en la siguiente imagen puedes ver un `Fragment` que es un Listado y otro que muestra contenido relacionado a un listado, ambos `Fragments` contenidos en una `Activity`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si quieres agregar un pedazo de UI con un mapa entonces usarías un [**MapFragment**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment), este es un ejemplo de una aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te sugiero realices el ejemplo de este tutorial para que entiendas como manejar los `Fragments`:

**[Utilizar Fragmentos En Una Aplicación Android](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/09/android-aplicaciones-fragmento/)**

Comment: De hecho la imagen que acabas de subir es justo lo que estoy buscando hacer, mi problema es que tengo una Actividad que contiene los Fragment y es un BottomNavigationDrawer, entonces lo que quiero es que en uno de los Fragment que abro al seleccionar un item del BottomNavigationDrawer, se muestre el mapa y además la información que yo quiero, así como lo muestras tu en la imagen. Para eso tendría que insertar el MapFragment dentro del Fragment que seleccione en el Drawer

Comment: la última imagen es un google maps con bottom sheet (fragment)